# Instantiate does not work in unity build, but in editor

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, build

I am trying to pre-load some buttons into a UI in Unity. It works absolutely fine in editor, but when i build it and start the .exe it does not populate the UI.

Here is my code:

```
void Start()
{
     InitializeButtons();
}

private void InititalizeButtons()
{       
    foreach (var name in buttonNames)
    {
        InstantiateButtons(name);
    }
}

private void InstantiateButtons(string name)
{
    var gameObject = Instantiate(SelectableButton, parentForButton);
    gameObject.GetComponentInChildren<TextMeshProUGUI>().text = name;
}
```

So for some reason this does not work in the build. In the editor it works just fine. Any ideas on why that could be?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

The Problem was, that i was doing the initialization in Start(). I have changed it to be in Awake() and now it works. So it seems to be a difference in script execution between the editor and build version.